# Django: Calling custom Model method from Form clean method. "Unbound Method"?

Tags: python, django

I'm having a problem while trying to call a custom Model method from my Form `clean` method.

Here is [part of] my model:
http://dpaste.com/hold/12695/

Here is my Form:
http://dpaste.com/hold/12699/

I'm specifically having a problem with line 11 in my Form:
`nzb_data = File.get_nzb_data(nzb_absolute)`

This raises the following error:

```
TypeError at /admin/main/file/add/

unbound method get_nzb_data() must be called with File instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

By this error I can assume I have to pass the method something (a File instance), however I don't really know what that means and how I can do it.

Can you let me know what I'm doing wrong here, and what can be done to resolve the issue?

---

**Solved** by making the `get_nzb_data` method a class method using the `@classmethod` decorator.

Comment: pastes just doesn't make sense at all for users with a similiar problem after you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call

```
nzb_data = File.get_nzb_data(nzb_absolute)
```

because your using the class, not an object.

You have two choices.

1. Make `get_nzb_data` a `@classmethod`.  See http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod
2. Create an instance of File and use that.  `temp_f= File(...)`.  Then `temp_f.get_dnb_data`.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something here, but I think that your method ´get_nzb_data´ should have a @classmethod decorator. Otherwise, it expects the ´self´ argument of the type File, and this gives that error.